# Add a link to barbuttonitem to open a view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Hi i have my app on ios8 the main view i have in the top bar a bar button item with the icon of twitter. I already have a view for twitter in my menu bottom bar, i would like when click the twitter icon on top bar i would like to open the view of twitter name TwitterViewController how can i achieve that?

I Tried adding the icon and dragging to my .h file but i cant do that, im using xcode 6.1.1

[image]

[image]

in this picture i put facebook and twitter icons, so when i click on those will open the view for facebook or twitter menu item depending which one user clicks

thank you.

pd: i just added this

```
- (IBAction)facebookaction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"boton facebook presionado");
    FacebookViewController *facebookViewController = [[FacebookViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:facebookViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

now it works when i click the icon opens the view i wanted but its like full screen i cant see the top bar and neither the bottom menu bar how i can fix this?

Comment: Have you set the custom class of the controller? (3 tab in the right utilities column)

Comment: i set custom class of each button is that correct? twitter: twitterbutton facebook: facebookbutton, i just added a screenshot to my post i dont know if thats ok

Comment: what i dont know if how to link those icons when clicked to open a specific view in this case facebook or twitter

Comment: @alexistkd you might want to use `IBAction` for the bar buttons, find out what are IBActions here:[What is an IBAction?](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-iphone-app-ios7/getting-started/what-is-an-ibaction)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Assistant Editor]

You can link Bar Button Item from Xib to the ViewController using Xcode 6.1.1. There are no chances of getting an error in a case similar to that.
Make sure that your XIB File's Owner has the right class file to which you are trying to link. Also make sure that you are taking the right IBOutlets.

[Assistant Editor](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ide/)
The Assistant button splits the Xcode editor in two, with your primary work document on the left and an intelligent Assistant editor pane to the right. The Assistant editor automatically displays files that Xcode determines are most helpful to you based on the work you are performing in the primary editor. For instance, if you are editing MyClass.m in the primary editor, the Assistant will automatically show the counterpart MyClass.h.

Comment: Any example? So i just drag from barbutton in the xib file to viewcontroller?

Comment: I just got it working following your tutorial but now i see my facebook view but without status bar and menu bottom bar whats wrong?

Comment: using this: - (IBAction)facebookaction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"boton facebook presionado");
    FacebookViewController *facebookViewController = [[FacebookViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:facebookViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}